# The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

When building my Eclipse RCP Application, I get the following error.

The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

I have included the org.eclipse.core.runtime library in my dependencies, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.pde/msg01027.html)

> Don't include the jar files manually [in the `plugin.xml` file). Use the dependencies tab in your plugin.xml editor to manage the dependencies on the plugins.

Here is the graphical illustration of what that means:

[alt text http://img91.imageshack.us/img91/923/eclipsercpruntime.png](http://img91.imageshack.us/img91/923/eclipsercpruntime.png)

Double-click on the `MANIFEST.MF` file, and through the 'Dependencies' tab, just add `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, and it will add other dependencies, including `org.eclipse.equinox.registry`, which includes your missing class!