# Java eclipse package compiling error

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have the following error in my eclipse package. I am trying to run an already existing code done by another person who is no longer available.

What does this mean?

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from       required .class files
    - The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from       required .class files
```

What does `cannot be resolved` and `indirectly referenced from       required .class` mean?

If i should import these class/interface where can i find them?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393284/the-type-org-eclipse-core-runtime-iconfigurationelement-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: It seems related to the creation of some eclipse plugin... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing code in another plugin, you need to make sure you declare that plugin as a dependency in your plugin's manifest.

Comment: what is plugin manifest?how to declare the plugin as a dependency?

Comment: Is your project a plugin project? If not, then my comment probably does not apply. Though if it's not then it's hard to see why you are hitting IConfigurationElement.

Answer (score 0):

You try to find the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement` class in which plugin， then you import the plugin in your project.

Comment: how to import the plugin in eclipse